# Big project: one version for all or own release cycle for every sub-project?

Tags: maven, release-management

Given we have a set of Maven artifacts with some dependencies between them. The artifacts are owned by various teams, and may be by several teams at once. This is our big project. For example:

```
projectX --- projectA

        |     \
   projectB   projectC
```

A question is: **what is better, to keep all the sub-projects in one big Maven project with one version, or let each team have its own artifact and its own release cycle and own version?**

The advantage of separating the teams is simple: if some team fails the build - others still using the old dependency provided by this team and experience no problems. Also in each global release we see which modules were changed and its easier to find a problem.

The disadvantage of separating the teams are:

1. team A changes projectX. now all the teams have to re-release their modules.
2. projectX's version is hardcoded in 3 modules, this is very error-prone solution. otherwise, the version may be described as LATEST or hardcoded in parent module, but who will force the teams to recompile their modules if projectX is changed?..

So what are the best practises for this typical situation?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's not a golden rule for that. I've worked on a big project (~90 maven modules/sub-modules... migrating from a maven1 to maven2!) and in those days we used a one big version for all for every release, while developing with SNAPSHOT versions.

But really depends in my opinion on two factors:

1. Release cycle needs.
2. Breaking interface responsibilities

It's really a matter of managing the development teams, and the maven's artifact version policy has to follow the management guide lines and not drive it (we have to always be in charge on our tools!)

### RELEASE CYCLE NEEDS

If a project/module needs to be released independently, it's bad to force other people working on other modules to do something.
[Maven versions range dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) could be used to allow others projects to depends on the just released artifact.

### BREAK INTERFACE RESPONSIBILITIES

What happen when a change in my module break an interface under the responsibility of another team? (or cause test failures, because you have integration test, right?!)

Can I change calling code? Can I change others module dependency to clearly warn that the current version is not compatible anymore?

Answering to these questions IMHO help to define a suitable version policy.